# php array for loop manage to display stackbar graph

Tags: php

I am trying to create a stacked bar graph using data from this table:

[image: Image of the table]

I need to get a result like this to make the graph:

```
['oxygen','cpap']   

 Prospecting  [10,12]
 Qualification [15,8]
```

A list of all the products and an array for each sales stage containing the quantities for each product.

I can get a list of product names from the table like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM target_products";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $product_name[] = $row['product_name'];
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to reorganize it in the format I need for the graph. How can I do it?

Comment: Your question seems to be lacking your efforts I'm afraid. We'd love to help you but you have to show us what you've tried that isn't working which should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just fetching the rows into an array with this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $product_name[] = $row['product_name'];
}
```

The general idea to get the structure you need is this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $graph_data[$row['sales_stage']][$row['product_name']] = $row['qty'];
    //              rows                  columns              values
}
```

This creates a structure where each row is a `sales_stage` and each column is a `product_name` belonging to that stage.

It's usually not quite that simple, though. Some stages may have products that others don't, so you may need to keep track of all the products and set missing values to zero for your graph data.

So keep a list of all the products as you go

```
$all_products = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $all_products[$row['product_name']] = 0;
    $graph_data[$row['sales_stage']][$row['product_name']] = $row['qty'];
}
```

Then after you have all the data, you can merge each row with the full list of products so the values for each `sales_stage` match up with the product headers.

```
foreach ($graph_data as $sales_stage => $stage_products) {
    $graph_data[$sales_stage] = array_values(array_merge($all_products, $stage_products));
}
```

Then you can get the results you need something like this:

```
echo json_encode([
    array_keys($all_products),
    $graph_data
]);
```

This may not be exactly what you need for whatever graphing library you're using, but it should get you on the right track.